# Update failing on DB2 i Series table (TIMESTAMP)

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update, db2-400

I am trying to update a timestamp on DB2 i Series table but it is failing.

```
UPDATE table1
SET datetime1 = CURRENT TIMESTAMP
FROM table1 tbl1
INNER JOIN table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID
```

The error I am getting is that `Keyword FROM not expected`.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark mentions, Db2 for IBM i doesn't support joined updates.

I'd close this as a duplicate, as this question has many answers on SO.
But since you're not actually using data from table 2,  this should do what you want..

```
UPDATE table1 
  SET datetime1 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
where id in (select id from table2);
```

Comment: @gmb for your info, `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are both valid.

Comment: Ah, my bad, sorry for the unneeded edit then! DB2 always surprises me... At edit time I did check that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` exists, but did not make sure that `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` does not!

Answer (score 3):

Such a syntax of the [UPDATE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=statements-update) statement is really not supported in Db2 for IBM i currently.